# 英語が残っている: 回答のチェックマークのツールチップ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

### 未採用

[image: non-accepted]

### 自分で採用

[image: accepted by me]

### 他の人が採用

[image: accepted by other]

Answer (score 1):

### 未採用

> この回答のおかげで問題が解決した、または一番役に立った回答として選びます。（もう一度クリックすることで取り消せます）

### 自分で採用

> 未解決にします。解決済みにした日付：

### 他の人が採用

> 質問主がこの回答を最も役に立つ回答として採用しました。採用日付：

「採用」という訳は用語が確定したら変わる可能性あり。